# Is possible to access URL via Controller with different directory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My basic module in project is accessible via this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/basic/
```

I have defined controller with mapping `@RequestMapping("/webpage.htm")`. So as we expect, this view is accessible via this URL: `http://localhost:8080/basic/webpage.htm`.

But I have also another module in my application. This module is accessible via URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/another/
```

And at this moment I would like to make mapping like this one: `http://localhost:8080/another/webpage.htm`. Is possible to handle this request by the same controller?

I have tried to do something like this in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/{module}/webpage.htm")
public ModelAndView handleMyRequest(@PathVariable("module") String module, 
                    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResonse response) {
    //my code
}
```

But this isn't working. Of course I can now access my view by new URL: `http://localhost:8080/basic/something/webpage.htm`.

According to this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules can I make working in this way mapping?

Comment: Your web-app ContextPath = "/basic" ? there is another web-app on a different ContextPath of "/another" ? If so there are old 2 mechanisms you can use. One is a redirect the other is a forward.  Google search terms "servlet dispatcher forward redirect" looks to have useful info.  You do not make it clear what "module" is, it is a web-app as per Java servlet specs?  web-app are mostly isolated deployments but there are mechanisms and techniques to share things.  I think Same Origin Policy is a red herring you have created for yourself. This relates to the external view of your data.

Comment: Ran out of comment room... and the reason you can not set ContextPath = "" (empty, i.e. the root context) ... once you do this then reason why you can not make the Spring dispatcher servlet global on "/*" is ?  Then you can write @RequestMapping("/basic/webpage.htm") and therefore @RequestMapping("/{module}/webpage.htm")